# Is kinetic energy conserved separately in different directions? Or does conservation only happen for total kinetic energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

If you have a collision, the momentum is conserved separately in each single direction. Now would this same idea apply to kinetic energy? How does the nature of conservation change due to it being a scalar?

Comment: What do you mean by "this same idea"? As you say, kinetic energy is a scalar, it doesn't have distinct components that could be conserved separately.

Comment: @DDD4C4U energy does not have a direction. It doesn’t make sense to ask if something which doesn’t have a direction is conserved in a direction. Energy is just conserved. No direction is involved.

Comment: @ACuriousMind you can speak of kinetic energy of different directions by splitting up the force law into x,y,z directions and the integrating those over the path, you can get k.e for different directions, right?

Answer (score 4):

Another way to look at it is that momentum is mass times velocity, and velocity is a vector: it has components in the x,y, and z directions.  Kinetic energy is mass/2 times velocity squared.  Velocity squared is the square of the *length* of the velocity vector, which is the same no matter what direction it is pointing; so kinetic energy does not have a direction associated with it.

Note that this is only true in a reference system that is fixed with respect to the center of mass of the system being measured.

If two observers are moving with different velocities past the system being observed, they will see different kinetic energies and momenta for the system.  However, as long as their velocities are constant, neither observer will see the kinetic energy of the system changing.  Also, each observer can easily calculate the kinetic energy and momentum of the system that would be observed in the system's own fixed center-of-mass system, and the observers will agree on those values.

Comment: I would recommend adding a comment that the moving observers will measure different KE and momentum they will each agree that energy and momentum are conserved.

Comment: Good suggestion; will do.

Answer (score 2):

Kinetic energy is *not* necessarily conserved, whereas total energy and momentum are.

In an elastic collision, for instance, kinetic energy is conserved as the initial kinetic energy of the particles involved is equal to the final kinetic energy of the particles involved. In this case, kinetic energy would be conserved.

On the other hand, in an inelastic collision, some of the initial kinetic energy is converted into a different form of energy, for example thermal. This means that, although the total amount of energy is still conserved, kinetic energy is not.

Concerning your points...

> If you have a collision, the momentum is conserved separately in each single direction.

Yes. This is true since momentum, a vector quantity, is always conserved. Being a vector, this means that you can pick a direction and resolve all momentum into its component in this direction and they will all "add up".

> Now would this same idea apply to kinetic energy?

No. Since kinetic energy is a scalar, it is simply a number associated with an object undergoing motion. It has no directionand therefore cannot be resolved in a particular direction.

> How does the nature of conservation change due to it being a scalar?

By "nature of conservation" I take it you simply mean "is it conserved or not". Kinetic energy is not always conserved just because it is a scalar. As I hope I explained properly at the start of this answer, total energy, a scalar, *is* always conserved. There are other scalars that are conserved, such as charge.

Comment: For a collision with no potentials ( i.e: only kinetic energies) then would kinetic energy be conserved separately in direction or not?

What's the intuition behind momentum being conserved in every direction but not k.e?

Comment: The law of conservation of momentum is fundamental and and has never been observed to have been violated. Similarly, the law of conservation of energy is fundamental. There is, however, no law for conservation of *kinetic* energy. Energy can be converted to and from different stores/types and kinetic energy is just one of these. In a collision where kinetic energy is not conserved, energy still is since the kinetic energy "lost" is converted into a different type of energy, such as thermal.